# Post a Json string in Xamarin

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, xamarin.ios

In my app, I am posting json string to the server in this manner:

```
string url = "my/url";
        HttpClient newClient = new HttpClient();

        string contentType = "application/json";
        JObject json = new JObject
        {
            { "id", "id" },
            { "apiKey", "apiKey" },
            { "EncryptedData", Data }
        };

        var jon = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json);
        var content = new StringContent(jon, Encoding.UTF8, contentType);
        var TaskPostAsync = await newClient.PostAsync(url, content);


        if (TaskPostAsync.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var contentString = await TaskPostAsync.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();}
```

The response I am getting is that it is not in a Json format. Where am I going wrong. Any help would be much appreciated. 
Data is a string.

Comment: Can you get what you server has received?

Answer (score 1):

By calling

```
 var jon = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json);
```

You are serializing it twice.

`JObject` is already JSON so all you need to do is call `.ToString` to get the JSON

```
//...

JObject json = new JObject
{
    { "id", "id" },
    { "apiKey", "apiKey" },
    { "EncryptedData", Data }
};

var content = new StringContent(json.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, contentType);

//...
```

Reference [Write JSON text with JToken.ToString](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ToString.htm)

Another option would be to use an anonymous object and then serialize that

```
//...

var model = new {
    id = "id",
    apiKey = "apiKey",
    encryptedData = Data
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, contentType);

//...
```

Comment: Tried it, still doesnt work. I have no idea whats going wrong.

Comment: {
  "hasError": true,
  "error": {
    "code": 601,
    "developer_message": "input not is JSON format",
    "user_message": "error message to show to the user"
  }
}

Comment: This is what server returns. If the the hasError is false, I would get the encryptedData back from the server.